# Reason for block multiplication of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Why do we multiply matrices in block form? What is the benefit? It doesn't seem to reduce the number of multiplications after all so, what's the value or the original intention? The texts I've seen don't seem to mention it other than that it's a method that's 'simpler' in that it allows for the multiplication of smaller matrices at a time.

Comment: I usually use block form only when the block structure meshes with structures of the underlying linear transformation. Most notably when one (or more) of the blocks are either the identity block or an all zeros block. So for me familiarizing my students with this is chiefly a pedagogical trick that comes in handy for some of them in their future studies. If you are really into algorithmic complexity there is [the Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm). It uses halving the matrix size much the same way as Karatsuba's algorithm.

Comment: Completely agree with Jyrki's comment, I would expand to say block multiplication can be really useful when your matrix is made up of blocks that are diagonal (particularly blocks that are multiples of the identity), all zero, or multiples of an all-ones matrix. It can also be really useful theoretically (eg incidence matrix of a structure where the blocks correspond to orbits of a group).